# Excel Office Script to Combine rows of a table if ID column is same

Tags: excel, typescript, office365, ms-office, office-scripts

My data is like this

| ID | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | g |  |
| 1 |  | g |
| 2 | g |  |
| 2 |  | g |

I want an office script only (Power automate) which can make my data look like this

| ID | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | g | g |
| 2 | g | g |

Basically merging rows if value ID matches

Thank you

I only know VBA code and Ive tried but so many errors

Comment: Follow [these](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Combining-rows-based-on-unique-id-and-combining-information/m-p/29466#M9962) steps for a PQ solution you can automate.

Comment: Cant do those steps on Excel Online for the office script to automate

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this just using formulas. No Office Scripts needed. Here's an example using formulas:

`=TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER($B$2:$C$5,$A$2:$A$5=D2)),",")`

In this example, column A is the ID column, columns B:C contain your data, and column D here contains the unique filter ID which is an external input for the formula. `TEXTJOIN` concatenates the elements to a string with a comma as the delimiter. With its second argument set to `TRUE` it removes blanks. From there, you can just use `TEXTSPLIT` to split the data using the comma as a delimiter and you should get the output you're looking for:

[image]

Comment: Keep in mind the OP wants: "office script **only** (Power automate)" This is a great solution, but with Excel formulas

Comment: @DavidLeal StackOverflow is not a code writing service. You can read more here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348591/how-to-flag-close-as-not-a-code-writing-service

Comment: sorry how your comment has to do with my comment? I just clarified that the OP is looking for a solution based on a different Excel tool, not using formula. Look at the tags listed in the question for example.